# Trouble with Screen Rotation Script

Tags: shell-script, xrandr, antergos

I am running Antergos linux with Gnome 3.18.2 on a Dell XPS 12 Convertible laptop/tablet, and am working on making the screen rotation more convenient.

I pulled a version of the following script from an [Ubuntu forums post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1675299) and modified it to match my display name, etc.  Each line has the expected result when run on its own, but when I run the actual script, nothing happens - no errors, no screen rotation, nothing:

```
 #!/bin/sh
rotation='xrandr -q --verbose|grep eDP1|cut -b45-50'
if [[ $rotation = "normal" ]] ;
then
  xrandr -o right
else
  xrandr -o normal
fi
```

Any ideas why this is not working as expected?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Seems like you are trying to set `rotation` via command substitution, but with wrong syntax. Try `rotation=$(xrandr -q ...)`. Right now you just set your `rotation` var as the string containing your plain command, hence the test has to fail and your screen stays the same.

Comment: Thanks Pidi, that did it!  If you want to post this as an answer rather than a comment, I will mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Quick Solution**

---

The way you set `rotation` results in your variable containing the written-out command you wanted to take the output from. 
What you want to do is using `command substitution` to store the output of your command in `rotation`.
You can achieve this by using `rotation=$(xrandr -q ...)` or `` rotation=`xrandr -q ...` ``.

**Background**

---

Command substitution executes your command in a subshell and stores its output written to `stdout` in your variable. It's a common thing to do, and I personally prefer using `$()`.

> You can read more on `command substitution` on the [Bash Hackers Wiki](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/cmdsubst).

By using single-quotes (strong quoting) you tell bash to not expand anything within the quotes. For example, with `a='$FOO'`, `$a` stays `$FOO`. Bash leaves the stuff you quoted untouched and directly shuffles it into your variable.

> More on quoting can also be found on the [Bash Hackers Wiki](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting).